# How can I link a xml file to a swfobject?

Tags: xml, url, flash, swfobject

Im having a problem with passing an xml url to my swf file, I get the swf but not the xml-data. It seems like the url to the xml somehow changes to the root url. I get this error:

http://www.nilan.dk/map.xml?nocache=1321265835080

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Even though I gave this path: http://www.nilan.dk/Files/Templates/Dealersearch/map.xml

This is my source:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Files/System/Scripts/swfobject.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
   var flashvars = {
      'file':               'http://www.nilan.dk/Files/Templates/Dealersearch/map.xml',
      'autostart':          'true'
   };<br />

   var params = {
      'allowfullscreen':    'true',
      'allowscriptaccess':  'always',
      'bgcolor':            '#ffffff'
   };<br />

   var attributes = {
      'id':                 'map',
      'name':               'map'
   };<br />

   swfobject.embedSWF('http://www.nilan.dk/Files/Templates/Dealersearch/map.swf', 'flashmap', '700', '600', '9.0.0', 'false', flashvars, params, attributes);
```